# GCM, Android, iOS, using the same Sender id and Server key/authorization key

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to share the same Server key and Sender id between your Android app and your iOS app? Otherwise I have to open two XMPP connections on the server which is a big mess.

How can I configure Google Developers to understand that I want to use the same keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should use the same sender_id and server key for Android and iOS given that they are the same application. Clients can receive/send messages from/to multiple servers (Developer console projects) but this is not necessary.

Your server makes an XMPP connection with GCM and send and receive messages via GCM. A single XMPP server can send to both Android and iOS clients.

Comment: So it's okey to just change the info.plist that google generated for me with the sender id that I got when I configured for gcm for Android? 

The fact that google asks for your bundle id makes you think that the sender id will somehow be bound to your bundle id

Comment: The Sender ID is the ID of your Google Developer Console Project. Each project can have multiple credentials. Thus both the info.plist and the google-services.json file will refer to the same Project ID, but will contain the platform's bundle ID or package name.

Comment: Can somebody point me out on how to create a ios configuration file with the credentials I already have for my Android app? Through this link - https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client - I always get a new one.

Comment: If you already have an Android app connected to Firebase then from the Firebase console that you have added your Android app and you can add your iOS app there and get a plist file for the same project.