# Can I send the Push Notification to the IOS and android devices using same GCM server key

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have to send push notification on ios and android devices. Can I use the same GCM Server Key.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956551/gcm-android-ios-using-the-same-sender-id-and-server-key-authorization-key

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, Yes. You just have to properly setup some stuff (APNS Certificates and all that stuff), I think you can start on this [Setting up a GCM Client App on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client) doc and then check out the related links from there.

Here's also a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdCXm_CroIs) by the Google Developers YouTube channel that I think you should check out.

Cheers!

Comment: Hello, I am exactly doing the same but when I configure it for iOS client it generates one for GCM server key but I already have one GCM server which I am using it for android devices since a month. Can I use the previous one.

Comment: AFAIK, I think so. Though I think new registration tokens are needed for the clients. Not entirely sure tho, why don't you try it out? You can just make use of the [dry_run](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) parameter to check if it's a success or not.