# GCM: How to use same sender id for both android and ios app?

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

I know that it is possible ([Android GCM: same sender id for more application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555180/android-gcm-same-sender-id-for-more-application)) but I don't know how to make it happen.

GCM is already working properly on our android app. Now we want to use it in our ios app too. But when I try to register ios app for gcm in google  developer console, it always registers a new app and provides a new sender id.

**NOTE**: No plan to use Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) yet.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956551/gcm-android-ios-using-the-same-sender-id-and-server-key-authorization-key

Answer (score 1):

Sender Id and api key have 1 to 1 relationship, so if you wish to use push notification in your ios as well, then, you have to use the same sender id. So you need not to register your app on  again.