# How to use same server api key for android and iOS GCM

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

Hello everyone i am working one of the push notification enabled application for both tech iOS & android. We are completely stuck now we need to use one server api key for both. Any useful suggestion will be appreciated thanks in advance.

**Already done**: we have already created the configuration file with the same package name and my android developer is using eclipse for.

> in iOS we are getting push notifications accordingly but not in android kindly help to figured out thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956551/gcm-android-ios-using-the-same-sender-id-and-server-key-authorization-key), you can and should use the same `sender_id` and `server key` for Android and iOS given that they are the same application so you don't have any problem with your `server key` since it's working on iOS.

You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client), an API key was saved on your app server that gives the app server authorized access to Google services. In HTTP, the `API key` is included in the header of your POST requests that send messages. In XMPP, the `API key` is used in the SASL PLAIN authentication request as a password to authenticate the connection.

Hope this helps!